# Read name property of package.json file with bash

Tags: json, node.js, bash, shell, zsh

I have this:

```
str=`cat package.json`
prop="name"
my_val="$(node -e "console.log(JSON.parse(${str})[${prop}]);")"
echo "$my_val"
```

I want to read the `name` property of the package.json file. I think this is close, but I am getting a JSON.parse error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)
    at [eval]:1:18
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:25:33)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:38)
```

anyone know how to fix?

This works:

```
prop="name"
my_val="$(node -e "console.log(require('./package.json')['$prop'])")"
echo "json val: '$my_val'"
```

but I am wondering how to do it the first way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a JSON parse error because you are trying to parse the string

```
"[object Object]"
```

You should change your bash script to have:

```
node -e "console.log(JSON.parse(\`$str\`)['name'])"
```

Note the backquotes! Your string is a multiline string.

Here's a run (in one of my project directories):

```
$ str=`cat package.json`
$ prop="name"
$ myval="$(node -e "console.log(JSON.parse(\`$str\`)['$prop'])")"
$ echo $myval
plainscript
```

**ADDENDUM**

In response to the OP wishing to use `require` instead of echoing the contents of the file into a string, the solution can be as follows:

```
$ prop="name"
$ my_val="$(node -e "console.log(require('./package.json')['$prop'])")"
$ echo $my_val
plainscript
```

**ADDENDUM 2**

You can even leave off the `console.log` if you use `-p`:

```
$ prop="name"
$ my_val="$(node -pe "require('./package.json')['$prop']")"
$ echo $my_val
plainscript
```

Comment: thanks let me try it, looks worthy. I updated the question - any way you know of to prevent 'undefined' from always being logged from `node -e`? The stdout includes 'undefined' at the end, I think there is a way to prevent that but I forget how.

Comment: Yes, remove the `-p`

Comment: ok cool, I forget what the `-p` arg is for, you can also use `||` apparently like so: `my_val="$(node -pe "console.log(require('./package.json')['$prop']) || ''")"`

Comment: I added a section to my answer which leaves off the `-p`. I think `-e` is just fine. `-p` prints the result of executing the whole script. You do _not_ want that if you have a console.log. I will add yet another section.

Comment: Okay I think it's looking better :)

Comment: ah nice, leaving off the `console.log` and using `-p` is nice

Answer (score 6):

On linux system there is command jq which can parse the JSON files

```
jq -r ".name" package.json
```

Comment: Quite cool! And if you are on a mac: `brew install jq` gets you that program.

Comment: `brew install jq` gets you that program *on MacOS*, not *nix...does `jq` come packaged with Bash v4?

Comment: @AlexanderMills It is completely independent of `bash` (just like `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `node`, etc), but if you want to work with JSON from the command line, it is *highly* recommended you install it. Your distribution may include it in its repository, but it is very simply to install manually; it's a single statically-linked binary. See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/